# How to have react app in the HTML without npm start or similar commands

Tags: reactjs

I'm kinda new to ReactJS and don't even know if it's possible but I want my react app to be working in the browser from the .html file. without the need for calling the server and have it, working, only that way. ( I don't mind having a server to serve it obviously) just need to be able to have by calling the .html file

the public/index.html file:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <script src="/my_library/my_library.min.js"></script> <!-- needed for the project in the same folder the index.html is -->
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        </noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <!--
            This HTML file is a template.
            If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

            You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
            The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

            To begin the development, run `npm start`.
            To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

the index.js (in src folder):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(App),
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The App.jsx in the src folder

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { MyContainer } from './components/MyContainer/index';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={ 'App' }>
                <header className={ 'App-header' }>
                    <h1 className={ 'App-title' }>
                    </h1>
                </header>
                <MyContainer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

PS: I have been able to add React to my file... But this particular component that I want to add only works with `NPM Start`. and as you can see in the index.html file shown above is says

```
This HTML file is a template.
If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
```

which is exactly what I aim to change. if any one can provide some guidance or help about this, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this [guide from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute) is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use `React` within an `HTML` file within a browser maybe you could just include the `React` library with a `script` tag as well as your custom React scripts with `script` tags as well. Their [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project)  has a nice example of just using React within an `HTML` file. I created a Codebox with their sample example for this below where the like button is using react. However, if you want to use `JSX` syntax you will have to use `Babel`, to transpile `JSX` into native `JavaScript`, and link the library like such:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

`create_react_app` gives you a lot of bells and whistles so you don't have to worry about *setting up build configurations* using tools such as `webpack`, `babel`, `eslint`, etc.. but this meant to give you a head start on building out an application so you can focus on the application itself and not configuration settings. Behind the scenes it's using [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) to serve up your application, but for your use case I think it would be **best to just add `React` as a `script` tag to an existing HTML page**

```js
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return e(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      'Like'
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Add React in One Minute</h2>
    <p>This page demonstrates using React with no build tooling.</p>
    <p>React is loaded as a script tag.</p>

    <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
    <div id="like_button_container"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="like_button.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully that helps!